# Angular Reactive form multiple checkboxes show as checked during second time visit although some values are false

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using angular 4 material design with reactive forms(FormControl) which include multiple checkboxes. During the first visit, all checkboxes show correct values. But during the second visit although some checkbox values are false UI shows all checkboxes checked.
HTML and Javascript code

```
    <mat-step [stepControl]="thirdFormGroup">
      <form [formGroup]="thirdFormGroup">
          <ng-template matStepLabel>MHE Facilities</ng-template>


     <mat-checkbox formControlName="Allopathy"  name="Allopathy">Allopathy</mat-checkbox><br>
     <mat-checkbox formControlName="Ayurveda"  name="Ayurveda">Ayurveda</mat-checkbox><br>
     <mat-checkbox formControlName="Homeopathy"  name="Homeopathy">Homeopathy</mat-checkbox><br>
     <mat-checkbox formControlName="Unani"  name="Unani">Unani</mat-checkbox><br>
     <mat-checkbox formControlName="Siddha"  name="Siddha">Siddha</mat-checkbox><br>
    </form>
            </mat-step>
```

Form Builder Code:

```
    this.thirdFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
     Allopathy : new FormControl(this.allopathy),
  Ayurveda : new FormControl(this.ayurveda),
  Homeopathy : new FormControl(this.homeopathy),
  Unani: new FormControl(this.unani),
  Siddha: new FormControl(this..siddha),
});
```

Binding value back to formcontrol:

```
     this.thirdFormGroup.patchValue({
     Allopathy : this.mheAppData.system_practice[0].checked,
     Ayurveda :this.mheAppData.system_practice[1].checked,
     Homeopathy :this.mheAppData.system_practice[2].checked,
     Unani :this.mheAppData.system_practice[3].checked,
     Siddha :this.mheAppData.system_practice[4].checked,
    });
```

Comment: Can i see the code for your formbuilder?

Comment: Hi, updated question with the code.

Comment: `this.mheAppData.system_practice[x].checked` contains a boolean value, right?

Comment: Yes it has boolean value.